# Bean Validation in a Camel environment?

Tags: java, xml, rest, maven, bean-validation

I am trying to use bean validation in one of my Rest API's which uses Camel.

I have a Request Address Bean and I want to put a null check for postcode. I have added the dependencies in my `pom.xml` and also added `@NotNull` annotation in my Address Bean.

Here is an extract of my `pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Extract of `AddressBean`:

```
@NotNull
@Min(value=6)
private String postcode;
```

I also have put a `ValidateAddress` class which checks for the violations that occurs in the bean and throw custom based exceptions.

My question is: how do I initiate this `ValidateAddress` class in my `camel-context.xml`?

I read some articles where they used `HibernateValidationProviderResolver` by adding `bean-validator` in the camel-context but I couldn't understand it.

Can anyone help me here ?